# Error La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de hacer una subconsulta la cual me traiga la cantidad cuando SI_Num_Conteo = 1 para ponerla en los articulos.

El problema esta en que los articulos en totales son mas que la cantidad, por ejemplo en este caso los articulos son 10 y la cantidad son 8
Alguna forma de decirle que si no esta la cantidad ponerle 0

Este es el resultado individual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si me hago entender bien, es complicado explicarlo.

```
SELECT SI_Num_Articulo,
(SELECT COALESCE(SI_Cantidad,0) FROM SI_Conteo 
WHERE SI_Num_Articulo = 201533 and SI_Num_Conteo = 1)
from SI_Conteo
where SI_Num_Conteo = 2
```

Comment: ok, si no lo puedes explicar dificil que lo podamos entender y ayudarte. tienes que ser claro como el agua. No velo la columna si_num_conteo por ningun lado. y obviamente "SELECT COALESCE(SI_Cantidad,0) FROM SI_Conteo 
WHERE SI_Num_Articulo = 201533 and SI_Num_Conteo = 1" devuelve mas de un registro

Answer (score 2):

Si la subconsulta te trae mas de un registro debes decidir que funcion quieres usar al llamarla :

```
Count(COALESCE(SI_Cantidad,0))
Max(COALESCE(SI_Cantidad,0))
Min(COALESCE(SI_Cantidad,0))
Sum(COALESCE(SI_Cantidad,0))
```

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Para ayudarte es necesario saber la estructura de la tabla. Si te entendí bien, lo que debes usar en la subconsulta sería:

`SELECT SI_Num_Articulo, 
        CASE WHEN (SI_Cantidad IS NULL) THEN 0 
        ELSE SI_Cantidad END AS 'SI_Cantidad'
FROM SI_Conteo
WHERE SI_Num_Articulo = 201533 and SI_Num_Conteo = 1`

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Vemos que el `COALESCE` está siendo mal aplicado, debido a que eso sirve para traer el dato no nulo del conjunto de columnas por registro que agregas.

Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces al hacer:

```
SELECT COALESCE(COLUMNA_02, COLUMNA_03,COLUMNA_04,'No data') AS REGISTRO 
FROM TABLA_01;
```

Obtendrás:

> ```
> +----------+
> | REGISTRO |
> +----------+
> | dato 01  |
> | dato 03  |
> | dato 02  |
> | No data  |
> +----------+
> ```